# How to save the text on a web page in a particular encoding?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, character, byte, html

I read following sentence from the [link](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding#how)

> Content authors need to find out how to declare the character encoding
>   used for the document format they are working with.
>
> Note that just declaring a different encoding in your page won't
>   change the bytes; **you need to save the text in that encoding too**.

As per my knowledge, the characters from the text are stored in the computer as one or more bytes irrespective of the 'character encoding' specified in the web page.

I understood the above quoted text also, except the last sentence in bold font

**you need to save the text in that encoding too**

- What does this sentence mean?
- Is it saying that the content author/developer has to manually save the same text(which is already stored in the computer as one or more bytes) in the encoding specified by him/her? If yes, how to do it and why it is needed to do? If no, then what this sentence actually mean?

Answer (score 0):

When you make a web page publicly available in the most basic sense you make a text file (that is located on a piece of hardware you own) public in the sense that when a certain adress is requested you return this file. 
 That file **can** be saved on your local hardware or **may not** be saved there (dynamic content). Whatever the case, the user that is accessing your web page is provided a file. Once the user gains posession of the file he  should be able to read it, that is where the encoding comes in play. If you have a raw binary file you can only guess what it contains and what encoding it is in, so most web pages provide the encoding that they return the file in alongside the file. 
This is where the bold text you ask about can be related to my answer - if you provide one encoding alongside the file (for example utf 8) but deliver the file in another encoding (ASCII) the user may see parts of the text or may not see it at all. And if you provide a static file it should be saved in the correct encoding (that is the one you told your file will be in).

As for the question how to store it - that is highly specific to the way you provide the file. Most text editors provide means to save a file in specific encoding. And most tools to bring up a page content provide convenient ways to give the file in a form that would be easy for the user to decode.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a note, probably because of confusion by some users.

The text tell us that one should specify in some form the encoding of the file. This is straightforward. Webserver usually cannot know the encoding of a file. Note if pages are delivered by e.g. a database, the encoding could be implicit, but web consider file as first class citizen, so we still need to specify encoding.

The note makes just clears that by changing the encoding, the page is not transcoded by webrowser. The page will remain byte per byte the same, just clients (browsers) will misinterpret the content. So if you want to change the encoding, you should specify the new encoding, but also save the file (or save and convert) to the expected encoding.  No magic will be done (usually) by web-servers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no text but encoded text.

The fundamental rule of character encodings is that the reader must use the same encoding as the writer. That requires communication, conventions, specifications or standards to establish an agreement.

*"Is it saying that the content author/developer has to manually save the same text(which is already stored in the computer as one or more bytes) in the encoding specified by him/her? If yes, how to do it and why it is needed to do?"*

Yes, it always the case for every text file that a character encoding is chosen. Obviously, if the file already exists it is probably best not to change the encoding. You do it by some editor option (try the Save As… dialog or equivalent) or by some library property or configuration.

*"save the text in that encoding too"*

Actually, it's usually the other way around. You decide on the encoding you want or need to use and the HTML editor or library updates the contents with a matching declaration and any newly necessary character entity references (e.g., does  need to be written as &#x1f6b2;? Does ¡ need to be written as &iexcl;?) as it writes or streams the document. (If your editor doesn't do that then get a real HTML editor.)